# spring boot security database authorization without password encoding

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to learn Spring boot security currently. I want to authorize with database without password encoding. 
What Configuration is need for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Spring security without password encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51208425/how-to-use-spring-security-without-password-encoding)

Answer (score 0):

```
        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    // configure AuthenticationManager so that it knows from where to load
    // user for matching credentials
    // Use BCryptPasswordEncoder
            auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        }

        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }

if u need to use password Encoder u just need t add this Bean
```

Comment: nooooo! i want to log in without any encoding password, if in db password is "root" when my password is "root".

Comment: see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51208425/how-to-use-spring-security-without-password-encoding